# Using setTag twice on one object?

Tags: android-layout, onclick, android

I have an onClickListener on a buttonView. The buttonView needs to detect which radioButton is selected in a radio group. But buttonView's setTag is already occupied by a JSON object that the onClickListener needs to access (via v.getTag = new JSONOBject). So, can buttonView have two (2) tags? I see there are two methods, setTag(Object ojb); and setTag(key, object);

Could I use that to my advantage?

Comment: i suppose setTag(0, new JSONObject) and setTag(1, yourothertag)... then you get ur jsonobject using getTag(0) and your other object using getTag(1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The buttonView needs to detect which radioButton is selected in a radio group.

Which it can do, without a tag, by calling a method on the `RadioGroup`.

> So, can buttonView have two (2) tags?

Create one tag object that holds onto your two other objects.

> I see there are two methods, setTag(Object ojb); and setTag(key, object); Could I use that to my advantage?

The two-parameter `setTag()` is really there for the OS and for libraries. App developers are discouraged from using it. Moreover, as noted above, you do not need it.

Comment: CommonsWare to the rescue like always. I made a simple Class to contain the two objects with return methods - then setTag for the button to that object. Could you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356733/getcheckedradiobuttonid-returning-useless-int